# Dimension formula for Cartan-type abelian.group Nichols algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

**Existence of a [root system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system)** has been established for [Nichols algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichols_algebra) $B(V)$ of a [Yetter-Drinfel'd-module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yetter%E2%80%93Drinfeld_category) $V$ (resp. braided vectorspaces $V$) over abelian groups (resp. with diagonal braiding $x_i\otimes x_j\mapsto q_{ij}x_j\otimes x_i$) already in 2000 by [Kharchenko](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005101). In 2008 [Schneider and Heckenberger](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0691) established root systems over nonabelian groups, under the condition that the root system / Nichols algebra be finite (-dimensional)!

**Having a root system means** among others that one has a set of irreducible sub-Yetter-modules $X_1\ldots X_n\subset B(V)$, with **multiplying as below a bijection** (no algebra morphism!):

$$B(V)\cong\bigotimes_{i=1}^nB(X_i)$$

**Dynkin-diagrams** can be drawn with Cartan Matrix $$q_{ij}q_{ji}=q_{ii}^{-A_{ij}}$$ but there are sporadic cases not corresponding to finite semisimple Lie algebras (triangle, exotic edge...) for low prime exponents. In these cases the classification of pointed Hopf algebras (Schneider /
 Andruskiewitsch) fails; the Weyl group is replaced by a -groupoid between different Dynkin diagrams.

**But in Cartan-type** it's the same as in the semisimple case - a root system $\Phi$!

- **Is is generally true that the "roots"** in both formulas coicide?
  $$|\{X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n\}|=n=|\Phi^+|\qquad or=\ldots?$$
- **So can I calculate the dimension of  $B(X)$ like that?**

$$dim(B(X))=\prod_{\alpha\in\Phi^+}dim(X_i)$$

...clearly $B(X_i)\cong k[x]/(x^{ord(q)})$ with dimension $ord(q_{ii})$) or infinite for $q=1$ (the *bosonic* $k[x]$).

- **So I just multiply the orders of respective the $q_{ii}$ for all roots?**

$$dim(B(X))=\prod_{\alpha\in\Phi^+}ord(q_{\alpha\alpha})$$

- **So especially for $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^k$ the dimension is the following?**

$$dim(B(X))=2^{|\Phi^+|}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, careful application of the theory of rootsystems verifies indeed these formulae.....farily streight-forward!